# How do you turn on and off window repaint while drag moving/re-sizing window in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How do you turn on and off window repaint while drag moving/re-sizing window in Windows 7?

When I drag a window or resize it, I just get a wireframe.  Some how this feature has gotten turned off.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for should be found here:

Control Panel -> System -> Adjust Appearance and Performance of Windows

-> Show Window Contents while dragging.
and 
-> Animate Windows when minimizing and maximizing.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel and type `appearance` in the search, it's the first result; filed under `System`.

I think the checkbox you're looking for is `Show window contents while dragging`.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a old question. Also don't have rep points to comment so I'll post as an answer. Slightly different location on my windows 7.
Control Panel -> System -> Performance information and tools -> Adjust visual effects

Then like the selected answer says, "Show window contents while dragging" should be checked.

Comment: You should type out the entire process. Although the "selected answer" is checked now, it could change down the road and your comment will not make sense. Also, checking your steps + the "selected answer, I could get the result. I could not with the selected answer steps only. Just a suggestions ;)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the right answer:

Control Panel -> System -> Adjust Appearance and Performance of Windows

-> Show Window Contents while dragging

Although mine was already checked, but still not working. So turning off that option, applying and turning it on again fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this in later versions of Windows (11):

Turn On or Off Show window contents while dragging in Visual Effects Performance Options

1 Run (Win+R) SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe to open Visual Effects Performance Options.

2 In the Visual Effects tab, check (on - default) or uncheck (off) Show window contents while dragging for what you want, and click/tap on OK.

(source: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-show-window-contents-while-dragging-in-windows-11.6560/)